# Sending multiple values to jquery ajax from a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use the following function for all the ajax calls in my site:

```
function ajaxcall(my_url, my_div, my_data)
        {
        $(my_div).append('<div style="text-align:center; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:100%;"><img src="/images/loading.gif" /></div>');
        $.ajax({ url: my_url,
        data: {data: my_data},
        type: 'get',
        success: function(output) 
            {
            $(my_div).html(output);
            }
        });
        }
```

It gets whatever URL I want and updates the DIV I want, so far so good. The problem is I also need to send 1 or more values and want to predict the names of those values.

```
<select class="formtext" name="car_id" id="car_id" onChange="ajaxcall('/ajax/carsetup.php', '#car_setups', $(this).val() )">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id="car_setups">select car</div>
```

So what this does is send my select value to the function, it works, however I don't know how to call that value anything, right now its called data but I want to name it whatever I wish, in this case car_id, dynamically, even worse I might want to send more values in that function's third *slot*. How would I get around this?

Right now `print_r($_GET);` gives me:

```
Array ( [data] => 2622 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
data: my_data,
```

instead of:

```
data: {data: my_data},
```

and you can then pass whatever values you look to your AJAX script, e.g.

```
<select class="formtext" name="car_id" id="car_id"
 onChange="ajaxcall('/ajax/carsetup.php', '#car_setups', {car_id: $(this).val()} )">
```

That said, you should consider attaching that AJAX call from within your JS itself, rather than inline in the HTML:

```
 $('#car_id').change(function() {
    ajaxCall('/ajax/carsetup.php', '#car_setups', {car_id: this.value});
 });
```

Comment: thanks, i cant seem to get that last part working, why is it important to not keep it inline?

Comment: Also, 

ajaxCall('/ajax/carsetup.php', '#car_setups', {car_id: this.value, variable: 1, variableother: 2}); 

doesnt seem to work

Comment: re: 1st query - inline handlers is _so_ 1990s...  not sure about second query - the syntax looks fine.  what does your debugger say?

Comment: i found out why, i copy pasted your code and you capitalized the function name, cheers mate, everything working perfect.